# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9001 in NextJS

Tags: server, compiler-errors, next.js, runtime-error, fetch-api

When I tried running code on my local mission by `npm run dev`, I am getting these error, tried changing code as per error. When I tried to console data it showing unreachable to call, tried with some code changes but did not work. Initially there was autoprefixer error rectified it but now this error pops up not able to solve any suggestions will be appreciated

```
import {comps as newsComps} from 'ui-comps-news'
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import pageLoad from '../lib/pageLoad'
import UI from '../components/UI'
import PCMPreview from '../containers/PCMPreview'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {loadData} from '../actions';

export default function Index(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const elements = [];

  Object.keys(newsComps).forEach(key => {
    elements.push({key, value: newsComps[key]});
  });
  const layout = JSON.parse(props.dataStr);
  const dataObj = {layout, elements, options: {}, styles: {}}
  dispatch(loadData({layout: dataObj.layout}));

  useEffect(() => {
    PCMPreview.init({dispatch, data: dataObj});
  }, []);


  return <UI {...dataObj} />
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { variant } = context.query;
  const data = await pageLoad(variant);
  return { props: { dataStr : console.log(JSON.stringify(data.layout)) } }
  
}
```

Error I am getting when running on `localhost:3000`:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9001
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9001,
  config: {
    url: 'http://localhost:9001/page?variant=undefined',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/page?variant=undefined',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '9001',
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/page',
      search: '?variant=undefined'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /page?variant=undefined HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:9001\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/page?variant=undefined',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:9001/page?variant=undefined',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'layout' of undefined
    at _callee$ (C:\Users\computer\Desktop\news-web\.next\server\pages\index.js:3664:58)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\computer\Desktop\news-web\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\computer\Desktop\news-web\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:22)
    at Generator.next (C:\Users\computer\Desktop\news-web\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:118:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\computer\Desktop\news-web\.next\server\pages\index.js:3607:103)
    at _next (C:\Users\computer\Desktop\news-web\.next\server\pages\index.js:3609:194)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Are you certain you have a server running on port `9001`? Also, can you share the code for the `pageLoad` function?

Comment: tried running server on 9001 but localhost refused, checking for any broken code, thanks for response.

Comment: Using https://127.0.0.1:3000 instead of https://localhost:3000 worked. Thanks. My use case was accessing other sites running via rewrites in local.